# How to get manager,employee pair output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I just require Required output as i posted below.This  question asked in an interview.

Table Structure:

```
create table #test
(
id int,
emp char,
roles char
)

insert into #test values(1,'A','M')
insert into #test values(2,'B','E')
insert into #test values(3,'C','E')
insert into #test values(4,'D','M')
insert into #test values(5,'E','E')
insert into #test values(6,'F','E')
insert into #test values(7,'G','M')
insert into #test values(8,'H','E')
insert into #test values(9,'I','E')
insert into #test values(10,'J','E')
```

Table:

[image: Table]

According to the table ,we have arrange the employee to his manager
M=manager
E=Employee
**Note:**The immediate Emp roles below Manager roles are their employees

**Ex:A is manager of B,C and D is manager of E,F**
Required output:

[image: Output]

lets see who's gonna answer !

Comment: What does the required output mean? You need to define the question more.

Comment: Look at the pattern of the output, as @Walker stated...please define your question better

Comment: Hint:  What does 'm' and 'e' mean? and then look at the pattern of the corresponding pairs

Comment: I have defined better question @jeff orris

Comment: @KavinChakaravarthi, I see that you have three answers that give you the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one more approach for any SQL Server version:

```
select t1.emp, t2.emp
from
(
select id,
case 
when t.roles = 'E' then (select emp from #test where id = (select max(id) from #test where id < t.id and roles = 'M')) 
end as emp
from #test t) t1
join 
#test t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id
where t1.emp is not null
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a clever question and I don't think I've seen it before.  Gosh, you actually have to think about what the pattern is that creates the output.

For those who don't see it, the "M" value goes in the first column for the corresponding "E" values before the next "M".  This would be easier to express in SQL Server 2012+, but here is one method in SQL Server 2005:

I'm pretty sure this is *not* the approach they were thinking of:

```
select tlm.emp, t.emp
from test t cross apply
     (select max(t2.id) as LastMId
      from test t2
      where t2.id <= t.id and t2.roles = 'M'
     ) tm join
     test tlm
     on tm.LastMId = tlm.id
where t.roles = 'E';
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2aabc/6).

Note to interviewers:  If you use this question, just change the database to SQL Server 2012+.  There are more elegant solutions with the functionality provided in that system.

EDIT:

This is actually the version I wanted to write:

```
select tm.emp, t.emp
from test t cross apply
     (select top 1 t2.emp
      from test t2
      where t2.id <= t.id and t2.roles = 'M'
      order by t2.id desc
     ) tm
where t.roles = 'E';
```

Comment: I agree...this is a clever question.  obviously interviewer wanted to see how much SQL user new and how user would 'tackle' the problem.  I had a similar question in an interview but involved 'CROSS JOIN'